# How to implement Spring JMS Window processing?

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-jms

I need to read messages from the JMS queue by batches (I have max number of records and time window parameters, whichever comes first).

Then I need to process the messages and do bulk updates & inserts into the DB.

How to implement this using Spring?

I was thinking about combining Spring Batch and JMS, but I am not sure if Spring Batch can work without stopping, I need to listen the queue indefinitely. I have the impression that Spring Batch is not for this streaming use case.

I know that in Kafka there is `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` where you can set batch processing to true, but unfortunately we don't use Kafka for now.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/container/jms/BatchMessageListenerContainer.html

There's not much documentation aside from the JavaDocs but there is a test case here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/5dc17b190e95c87463f96bc27d8d5292c46006ff/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/container/jms/BatchMessageListenerContainerTests.java

Comment: do you think Spring Batch can be used here for this streaming usecase? I thought Spring Batch is more like one time run job by scheduler or something like that.

Comment: It wouldn't be a batch job per se, but that project provides this batching container.

Comment: Looks like this class is absent in the latest spring boot version, also looking at the code here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/5dc17b190e95c87463f96bc27d8d5292c46006ff/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/container/jms/BatchMessageListenerContainer.java I don't see how it can help with reading messages by batches :(

Comment: Oh; right, sorry; yes, this container still calls the listener one-at-a-time but encompasses multiple records in a single transaction. Different use case to yours; I will delete this answer. AFAIK, there is no equivalent to the Kafka (and RabbitMQ) batch modes with JMS.

Comment: I will defer the deletion because you don't have enough reputation (10k) to see deleted answers.

Comment: I am ok to read one-at-a-time and accumulate multiple records, let me try to use this BatchMessageListenerContainer

Comment: You can do with without this special container, just use CLIENT_MODE acks and only ack after you have accumulated and processed the batch. No need for the extra complexity of this container (unless you are using JMS transactions).

Comment: From what I see in the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html :"CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE": Automatic message acknowledgment after successful listener execution. Jms listener executes once per message, I don't understand how to ack a bunch of messages. Do you have some example by any chance?

Comment: You are correct (it's been a long time since I worked with JMS). You have to create your own consumer on a session (e.g. via `JmsTemplate.execute()`; then set its `MessageListener` to receive messages. Calling `acknowledge()` on the last message in the batch will ack them all.

Comment: and as for the messages, do I need to just accumulate them in the queue? then once the queue has the size of my batchSize I process the messages then ack the last message and empty the queue, something like that?

Comment: Yes, something like that.